# Error "Invalid parameter number" al inserta registros en tabla desde archivo CSV

Tags: php

Quiero leer un archivo CSV que tiene tres campos: cod, nom e importe; e insertarlos en una tabla que tiene las siguientes columnas:

```
TABLA
cod integer
nom varchar(45)
importe decimal(8,2)
periodo integer
fecha date
```

Este es el código:

```
$registro = fopen($ruta.$formato_archivo, "r");
while (($data = fgetcsv($registro, 4096, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $sth = $BD->prepare("INSERT INTO tabla (cod, nom, importe)
                VALUES (:cod, :nom, :importe)");
    $cod = $data[0];
    $nom = $data[1];
    $importe = $data[2];

    $sth->bindParam(':cod', $cod, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->bindParam(':nom', $nom, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->bindParam(':importe', $importe, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $sth->execute();
}
```

Y me muestra el error:

> Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in line (línea del execute()).

Y no inserta ningún registro.

Comment: Y dónde estás declarando `$cod` `$nom` e `$importe`? Creo que te falta la lógica para asignar esas variables a partir de $data, que es un array.

Comment: Agregué los campos del array.

Comment: Citaré tres posibles causas, **dando por hecho que has comprobado que la conexión a la BD se hace correctamente**: 1. En bindParam no estás indicando el **tipo de dato**: http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindparam.php 2. ¿**Estás seguro que hay datos** en `$cod, $nom, y en $importe` haz un `print_r ($cod."->".$nom."->".$importe);` para comprobarlo. 3. En el binding pon **comillas dobles**, ejemplo: `$sth->bindParam(":cod", $cod);`, pues el CSV puede tener valores como `O'Donnel`, entonces tendrás un problema.

Comment: @A.Cedano 1. le puse tipo de dato PDO::PARAM_STR (cod es integer, nom es varchar e imorte es decimal). 2. Sí hay datos, ya probé. 3. Usé comillas simples y dobles y funciona igual En el manual usan simples. No será que mi tabla tiene más campos? Probé con una tabla que tiene los tres campos y sí funciona, pero si tiene más campos, sale ese error.

Comment: Si hay más campos (columnas) en tu tabla no debería haber problema, ya que el INSERT especifica las columnas de inserción de los datos, **a no ser que exista una columna que no acepte nulos y que la misma no sea una de las del INSERT** en ese caso el sistema trataría de asignar `NULL` a dicha columna. Nota: a. Si `cod` es del tipo `INT` debería ser `PDO::PARAM_INT` Otra posible causa es que el archivo no tenga en cada línea 3 valores separados por comas. b. Lo de las comillas simples es como precaución, ya que puede haber nombres como O'Donnel. Si usas comillas simples podría dar error.

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que has echo `var_dump($data)`y todo ha ido correcto.

Has probado a cambiar el parametro PDO que se le pasa ?

`$sth->bindParam(':cod', $cod, PDO::PARAM_INT);`

Con el tipo Decimal de "importe" al crear la tabla puede que tengas problemas.
Revisa los TIPO de campos en la base de datos y lo que estas insertando.

Comment: Ya funciona. Modifiqué tres cosas: 1) $importe = floatval($data[2]); 2) Los campos que quedan vacío que acepten nulos. 3) Cambié $sth->bindParam(':cod', $cod, PDO::PARAM_INT); <br/> Y ahora cómo hago con la puntuación?